# Join specific columns of matching rows

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
patientcA   1   2   NA   NA  b   c
patientcB   NA  NA  3     4  b   c
patientdA   3   3   NA   NA  d   e
patientdB   NA  NA  5     6  d   e
```

How can I join columns 2,3,4 and 5 for those rows which match in column 1 except for the last character. In this case, first two rows match except for the last character; and last two rows do the same. So my expected output would be:

```
patientcA   1   2   3   4  b   c
patientcB   1   2   3   4  b   c
patientdA   3   3   5   6  d   e
patientdB   3   3   5   6  d   e
```

I have tried something like this, but I don't know what to write as `else` argument. Moreover I think this is not the best approach:

```
new_data$first_column<-ifelse(grepl('A$', original_data$first), original_data$first, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you might consider a `tidyverse` approach that uses `separate` to put the last character of column 1 into a new column, and `fill` to replace `NA` with values for the same patient.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("patient", "letter"), sep = -1) %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  fill(V2:V5, .direction = "downup")
```

**Output**

```
  patient  letter    V2    V3    V4    V5 V6    V7   
  <chr>    <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1 patientc A          1     2     3     4 b     c    
2 patientc B          1     2     3     4 b     c    
3 patientd A          3     3     5     6 d     e    
4 patientd B          3     3     5     6 d     e
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a vectorized function like `CC()` below, that completes columns, then split-apply-combine with `by`.

```
CC <- Vectorize(function(x) if (any(is.na(x))) rep(x[!is.na(x)], length(x)) else x)

res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, by(dat, substr(dat$V1, 8, 8), CC))
res
#            V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# c.1 patientcA  1  2  3  4  b  c
# c.2 patientcB  1  2  3  4  b  c
# d.1 patientdA  3  3  5  6  d  e
# d.2 patientdB  3  3  5  6  d  e
```